# Missing jQuery Mobile icons on Opera Mini

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, opera-mini

I'm creating elements like that:

```
<a href="#nav-panel" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-c ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon"></a>
```

It works ok on browser like Chrome, Android Browser, Opera, etc. but on Opera Mini icons are not visible. It's just an empty space.

jQuery Mobile version is 1.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icons on websites such as **fontawesome** and **bootstrap** often make use of using a custom font which is then setup by using the `font-face` CSS rule. `font-face` is not currently supported by Opera Mini.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface

Reading the following link, it looks like Opera Mini does not allow custom fonts and instead uses fonts available on the device.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#typography

Have you tried setting `Use bitmap fonts for complex scripts` in the `opera:config`, maybe this will work?
http://blog.tavultesoft.com/2014/07/enable-custom-fonts-in-opera-mini.html

Edit:

Appears the issue was that jQuery mobile uses `.SVG` for the icons and falls back to `.png` if that fails. The path was not set up correctly for the `.png`.

Comment: On http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/ every icon is visible from opera mini so I think it's not a problem with opera settings.

Comment: Ah so it says here it tries to use svg and then png if the svg fails. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/ Can you see whether opera mini is trying to obtain these locally or remote, how is it behaving differently from your website and the jquery UI one?

Comment: I had wrong path to .png files so that was the case.

Comment: Ah brilliant, strange that it is falling back to png though, I thought opera mini could handle svg files. http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg